# Borrow mutable inside of `match` arm

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, refcell

I'm new to Rust, so I'm sorry if this question has an absolutely obvious solution. I cannot find cleaner way to write the code below. I know this code cause `panic` because of `container` is already borrowed.

```rust
return match &container.borrow().parent {
  Some(parent) => {
    container.borrow_mut().active = false;
    Layout::move_focus(parent, direction, f)
  }
  None => Rc::clone(container),
}
```

Problem there is preventing me from changing a `container` attributes while I'm `match`ing `parent`. Because of `match`ing `parent` and changing `active` state, that are independent in my code, I think this code is safe.

I also know this can be solved by moving mutable borrow out of `match` and changing `match` to `if let` as is shown in the code below. Variable `active` is set to `true` at the beginning.

```rust
{
  container.borrow_mut().active = false;
}
if let Some(parent) = &container.borrow().parent {
  return Layout::move_focus(parent, direction, f);
}
container.borrow_mut().active = true;
Rc::clone(container)
```

Is there a more readable and cleaner way to write code with the same functionality?

If it is important for solving this problem the whole code implements nodes that have containers on widgets inside, where containers must know their parents.

Function declaration:

```rust
pub fn move_focus(
  container: &Rc<RefCell<Container>>,
  direction: Direction,
  f: fn(&RcCon) -> Option<Rc<RefCell<Container>>>,
) -> Rc<RefCell<Container>>
```

Structs:

```rust
pub struct Container {
    pub items: Vec<Item>,
    pub layout: Layout,
    pub direction: Direction,
    pub parent: Option<Rc<RefCell<Container>>,
    pub act_index: usize,
    pub active: bool,
}

pub enum Item {
    Container(RcCon),
    Widget(Holder),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can borrow **whole** container as `mut` firstly, and then do operations on it.

```rust
let mut c = container.borrow_mut();

return match c.parent {
  Some(parent) => {
    c.active = false;
    Layout::move_focus(parent, direction, f)
  }
  None => Rc::clone(container),
}
```

Also passing `&Rc` as an argument is not idiomatic rust. Prefer passing `Rc` directly.

Comment: This cause cannot borrow `c` as mutable on `c.active = false` because `move_focus` uses immutable later. Add output of `move_focus` to variable and return variable solves this problem.